# VC++ Redirect Input/Output on Windows Interface

Tags: visual-c++

I am new to C++ and I need to direct my Input and Output to the window screen. For example if I write a simple program in C++

include 
using namespace std;

```
int main ()
{
  int i;
  cout << "Please enter an integer value: ";
  cin >> i;
  cout << "The value you entered is " << i;
  return 0;
}
```

and we get I/O on the command prompt. But I want it on the windows interface and it should ask the questions and we could write it.

I really need help and thanks a ton in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to display as a GUI then you'll have to use a GUI framework and you won't use the standard input and output consoles.

You have several options for C++: Win32, MFC, Trolltech Qt, wxWidgets, Winforms/WPF (managed C++).

Or if you want to keep it simple you can change to C# and use WinForms or WPF.